# Swapped BTC for ETH using Bity.com en MEW but lost funds

Tags: ether, myetherwallet

I used bity.com service to convert 0.2 BTC for ETH and bity did not deliver my ETH, is this a scam?

This is the confirmation message i got on MEW: Your TX has been broadcast to the network. It is waiting to be mined & confirmed. During ICOs, it may take 3+ hours to confirm. Use the Verify & Check buttons below to see. TX Hash: 0x851c85bc5d365209db738104ef84c79c04ff10ed3e0c41b5a2f122e36863eb6f
View your transaction

When I check the Tx or click on the link it says it doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

If your transaction is not showing on Etherscan then it did not get mined. Please re-send your transaction and check what gas price & how long it will take via https://ethgasstation.info/

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x851c85bc5d365209db738104ef84c79c04ff10ed3e0c41b5a2f122e36863eb6f